# Script works but has error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null at HTMLAnchorElement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a stylized navigation for a homepage slider but getting some console errors - even though the script is doing what I want it to for the most part. That's to add classes to the adjacent sibling elements on mouseover of the focused element.  Like the pen shows, its working for the most part, but I'm getting errors on every mouseover, saying it **Cannot read property 'classList' of null.**  Could anyone give me an idea of why this is and a fix?

```js
var sliderNav = document.getElementById('sliderNav');
var paraIns = new Parallax(sliderNav);
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');

thumbs[3].classList.add('active');

for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
  thumbs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    this.classList.add('active');
    this.previousElementSibling.classList.add('adjacent');
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('adjacent');
    this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.classList.add('adjacentx2');
    this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.classList.add('adjacentx2');
  });
  thumbs[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    this.classList.remove('active');
    this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('adjacent');
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('adjacent');
    this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('adjacentx2');
    this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('adjacentx2');
  })
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.slider {
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1200px;
}
.slider__navigation {
  pointer-events: unset !important;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 240px;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14%;
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail .thumbnail__img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: lightgray;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  left: 13% !important;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  left: 27% !important;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  left: 56% !important;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  left: 71% !important;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  left: 84% !important;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(3), .slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 4;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(2), .slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  z-index: 3;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail.active {
  z-index: 5;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail.active .thumbnail__img {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail.adjacent {
  z-index: 4;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail.adjacent .thumbnail__img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail.adjacentx2 {
  z-index: 3;
}
.slider__navigation .thumbnail.adjacentx2 .thumbnail__img {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div id="sliderNav" class="slider__navigation" data-relative-input="true">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.2">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.4">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.6">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.8">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.6">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.4">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.2">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error means that one of those `.previousElementSibling` or `nextElementSibling` properties is `null`.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, sorry. It was actually misleading.

Let me try again; querySelectors return a static list, and this can cause issues when referencing it later in code. If the element changes, the list is stale. 

I'd suggest either use the event target or give the elements an id and select them explicitly where required.

Comment: @StevenStark In this particular case there's no problems with the static list. Rather the issue is, that when you're hovering/blurring the first element, there's no previous, or previous previous, and no next or next next element for the last element in `#sliderNav`, hence trying to refer `classList` of those elements fails.

Comment: @Teemu aah, right, I didn't look close enough at the sibling logic. good catch.

Comment: Additional to Guy Yogev's answer, you might want to use `mouseenter/leave` events instead of `mouseover/out`s, because the latter fire also when these events occur inside the link (they're bubbling up to the links and trigger the event on the link as well). This is not a problem in the example code, but will arise, if you will have more than one element within the links.

Comment: @Teemu That makes a ton of sense.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sliderNav = document.getElementById('sliderNav');
var paraIns = new Parallax(sliderNav);
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');

thumbs[3].classList.add('active');

for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
  thumbs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log(!!this.previousElementSibling, !!this.nextElementSibling);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.slider {
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1200px;
}

.slider__navigation {
  pointer-events: unset !important;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 240px;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14%;
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail .thumbnail__img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: lightgray;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  left: 13% !important;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  left: 27% !important;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  left: 56% !important;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  left: 71% !important;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  left: 84% !important;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(3),
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(2),
.slider__navigation .thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail.active {
  z-index: 5;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail.active .thumbnail__img {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail.adjacent {
  z-index: 4;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail.adjacent .thumbnail__img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail.adjacentx2 {
  z-index: 3;
}

.slider__navigation .thumbnail.adjacentx2 .thumbnail__img {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div id="sliderNav" class="slider__navigation" data-relative-input="true">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.2">
      <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.4">
      <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.6">
      <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.8">
      <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.6">
      <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.4">
      <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.2">
      <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first/last elements have no previousElementSibling/nextElementSibling. see console logs when you hover over the elements.

Comment: Ah, when the user gets too close to the edges and there's less siblings than the script is expecting, the ones it cant find returns null, that makes sense!  Thank you!